# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'quotes' since it isn't a known property of 'app-quote-create'

Tags: angular

I have read all the related questions and answers, but so far no luck, please help.

my declarations and imports look fine here in 
app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { QuoteCreateComponent } from './quote-create/quote-create.component';
import { QuoteListComponent } from './quote-list/quote-list.component';
import { OrderbyPipe } from './orderby.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QuoteCreateComponent,
    QuoteListComponent,
    OrderbyPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the property or field looks fine to me here in
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "angular quote ranks";
  quotes = [
    {body: 'I never am really satisfied...', author: 'Ada Lovelace', rating: 25},
    {body: 'To be, or not to be...', author: 'Prince Hamlet', rating: 2},
    {body: 'There are risks...', author: 'John F. Kennedy', rating: 23}
  ];
  createQuote(quote) {
    console.log(quote);
    this.quotes.push(quote);
  }
  deleteQuote(quote) {
    const idx = this.quotes.indexOf(quote);
    this.quotes.splice(idx, 1);
  }
}
```

the binding looks fine to me here in
app.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div class='container'>
  <app-quote-create [quotes]="quotes" (createQuoteEvent)="createQuote($event)">
    </app-quote-create>
  <app-quote-list [quotes]="quotes" (deleteQuoteEvent)="deleteQuote($event)">
    </app-quote-list>
</div>
```

I tried to follow what the error message is saying but I am not understanding it fully.
The error message is:

```
compiler.es5.js:12814 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'quotes' since it isn't a known property of 'app-quote-create'.
1. If 'app-quote-create' is an Angular component and it has 'quotes' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-quote-create' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div class='container'>
  <app-quote-create [ERROR ->][quotes]="quotes" (createQuoteEvent)="createQuote($event)"></app-quote-create>
  <app-quote-list [quo"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:20
Can't bind to 'quotes' since it isn't a known property of 'app-quote-list'.
1. If 'app-quote-list' is an Angular component and it has 'quotes' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-quote-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("te [quotes]="quotes" (createQuoteEvent)="createQuote($event)"></app-quote-create>
  <app-quote-list [ERROR ->][quotes]="quotes" (deleteQuoteEvent)="deleteQuote($event)"></app-quote-list>
```

THANKS! the error was here, i was missing the property in this component:
 quote-create.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-quote-create',
  templateUrl: './quote-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quote-create.component.css']
})
export class QuoteCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() quotes;
  @Output() createQuoteEvent = new EventEmitter();
  newQuote = { body: '', author: '', rating: 0};
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(formData) {
    console.log(formData)
    console.log(this.newQuote);
    this.createQuoteEvent.emit(this.newQuote);
    this.newQuote = { body: '', author: '', rating: 0};
  }
}
```

My Github is: https://github.com/mruanova/angular-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from your [`app-quote-create` component source](https://github.com/mruanova/angular-quotes/blob/master/src/app/quote-create/quote-create.component.ts), you do not have an `@input` property with the name of `quotes`, thus you cannot pass the App Component `quotes` object to it.

If you look at the compiler output, it is not telling you that App Component does not have a quotes object - it is saying that `app-quote-create` does not have a field that accepts it as an input (as we saw by the source).

```
compiler.es5.js:12814 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'quotes' since it isn't a known property of 'app-quote-create'.
```

(This compiler is quite smart - make sure to read it's output!)

If you want to solve this, add this to your `QuoteCreateComponent` (untested/from memory):

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input /* <- add this */ } from '@angular/core';

export class QuoteCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  // Add this
  @Input() quotes: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it without using INPUT. The project compiled successfully, the error was in the browser console and not in the terminal, the property QUOTES was missing in another component called APP-QUOTE-CREATE which is not the main component that I added here, so the code above is correct.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you could mark it as the answer that would be great :)